# How to move in CSS the whole line of "Top Stories" on the screenshot below to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, text-alignment

I would like to move the whole line of "**Top Stories**" circled in red on the screenshot below to the bottom to allow the "Top Stories" to be displayed at the bottom of the screen and not at the top as it currently is:

[image]

When I try to add `bottom:0px` to the `div` whose css class is `top-stories-bar top-stories-bar-with-thumbnail`, hoping I can move it completely to the bottom of the screen , nothing changes:

[image]

**How could you manage to move the whole line of "Top Stories" *to the bottom* of the home page to allow the news to be scrolled at the bottom unlike at the top as it is currently?**

---

It doesn't work when I use:

```
position:relative; 
top:90vh;
height:10vh;
```

We no longer see the "**Top Stories**" line. Applying this code will make the "**Top Stories**" row completely disappear which I would just like to move to the bottom of the homepage screen. I look forward to your suggestions please.

You can try it yourself on [https://www.themehorse.com/preview/newscard-pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StbES.jpg) and you'll see that it completely hides the whole "**Top stories**" line that I'm trying to just move to the bottom of the screen.

I really need your help.

---

When I use:

```
bottom: 0px;
position: fixed;
```

It works but it's hidden behind the text of the articles (publications) of the page and almost invisible.

How to place it in front of the text of articles or publications ???

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <nav>
       navigation
    </nav>
  </body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
   nav {
     position:relative; 
    top:90vh;
    height:10vh;
  }
```

First give your nav element a height of view port units (vh). Then set the position as relative. Finally, give it a top of 90vh.

**Note** that you didnt present the html in your question, so the units and their values would most likely be different. Relative position works by shifting it relative to its containing element. If you still need to make the code work, you could use the absolute position. In this case, you may also need to change the width measurement of the nav element. Another option is to use fixed, to allow the user to see the navbar as he scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

For the “bottom: 0px;” to work, you also should apply “position: fixed” to the class to achieve your goal.

You can read more about css positioning here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

I finally opted for:

```
height: 60px;
bottom: 0px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 5;
```

And it works very well. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

To place the text in front of the article-text, you could apply the "z-index" property. This property specifies the stack order of an element. So when you apply a higher "z-index" (the default is auto, which corresponds to 0) to the text you want in front of the article-text, it will work.

On [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) page you can read more about the "z-index" property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).